# Intersection of subspaces of a vector space is a subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space, and $W$ and $X$ be subspaces of $V$. I want to prove that $W\cap X$ is a subspace of $V$.

This seems pretty intuitive to me but I do not know how to prove it. I also don't understand what goes with two subspaces intersecting to make another subspace.

Comment: A good place to start is with the definition of a subspace.

Comment: What axioms must $W$ and $X$ satisfy in order to be subspaces of $V$? Check that those axioms are also satisfied by $W\cap X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good visualization is two planes through the origin in $\mathbb{R}^3$ intersecting in a line. A plane through the origin is a two-dimensional subspace, and a line through the origin is a one-dimensional subspace. (You probably haven't seen the formal definition of dimension at this point, but you can see how this makes sense).

To prove that something is a subspace, what things do you need to prove?

Can you see that if those things are true about each of $W$ and $X$, they'll be true about the intersection as well? Remember, the intersection is the set of vectors that are in *both* $W$ and $X$.

Comment: So since both of these are subspaces of the same vector space they both intersect the origin which means they both hold a coordinate point that is the same. SO would that be enough to prove that those combined are a subspace of V?

Comment: The intersecting planes provide a good *visualization* of two subspaces intersecting in a subspace. To do the proof, forget the planes and focus on the definitions. What do you need to show to prove that a set of vectors is a subspace? There are three things to show. They should be in your text.

Comment: For my text to prove for a subspace we only use two axioms that deal with closure which is showing the addition of two vectors is in the vector space and that the vector can be scalar multiplied and still be in the vector space

Comment: Plus containing 0, right? In any event, that's how you proceed. Can you show that those two or three things are true?